# How to send commands to terminal and receive data from it?

Tags: command-line, c++, c, qt-creator

Linux, Qt Creator. I ran this in a debugger:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char p[1000];
int main()
{
    scanf("%s",p);
    return 0;
}
```

It works. However, no terminal appears when I double click the executable (Windows does this in contrast to Linux). I assume I need to create one. For example, like this:

```
system("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator");
```

Now I need to communicate with it. How? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to compare running binary files in windows or linux via command-line, just browse to your `xxx.c` file then run `gcc xxx.c -o xxx` and then `./xxx` where `xxx` is your filename. Or maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763719/c-program-that-executes-bash-commands-inside-xterm-with-execl

Answer (score 1):

I created a program invoking a program invoking a program. The key line in the first is:

```
execl("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator", "/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator",
        "-e", "/home/kkk/build-untitled-Desktop-Debug/untitled",
        "/home/kkk/Downloads/1.pdf", (char*) NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows distinguishes between "Console-only" executables and GUI executables and if you start one of the former it would open the console for you.

Linux doesn't have this distinction - all executables are pretty much the same. If you try to start one from a file manager (where you do the double clicking) it would run, try to read from the standard input, receive the EOF mark (because the program is not attached to any terminal) and quit.

Some file managers can offer you the option "Execute in Terminal". Whether your file manager can be configured to do so I do not know.

Comment: Great answer. However. I created such a terminal-executed label for my file. It works. But I planned to use it as a tool. For being "default program". For pdf-files (to be "Open with..." one). So I click on pdf-file and my program should start. Here it does not work. At all. Why?..